# How do I find the matrix of the linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Going through the text on Linear Algebra by A. O. Morris (2nd edition) I am trying to understand something on linear transformations.
There is a problem where the R-bases of U and V are given as

```
{u1, u2} and {v1,v2,v3} respectively and the linear transformation from U to V is given by
Tu1=v1+2v2-v3
Tu2=v1-v2
```

The problem is to
a) find the matrix of T relative to these bases,
b) the matrix relative to the R-bases

```
{-u1+u2,2u1-u2} and {v1,v1+v2,v1+v2+v3},
```

and c) the relationship between the two matrices.
From the very good treatment of the subject here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12383/determine-the-matrix-relative-to-a-given-basis I figured out that the first matrix T has columns

`(1,2,-1),(1,-1,0)`.

then for part b) I figure out Matrix A which I take to be the transform of ordered basis of U to standard basis of U as

```
((-1,2),(2,1)}
```

Matrix B which I take to be the transform of ordered basis of V to standard basis of V as

```
{(1,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,0,1)}
```

I then find inverse of B and form the product

```
[B]inv.C.A as the answer to part c).
```

Somehow I do not seem to get it. I am completely at sea. I would appreciate help to understand this.
My sincere apologies for not being able to use Latex.

Comment: This is not a programming question....this is probably best asked at the math exchange. Have you tried there?

Comment: Thanks but sorry for posting to the wrong forum. I have migrated the problem to the right forum.